# Did we see Daniel, the cylon John murdered, in "Someone to Watch Over Me"?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

The Last Cylon, Ellen Tigh, stated that Daniel was musical and that John murdered him.  In the episode "Someone to Watch Over Me", Starbuck meets the piano player seemingly her Father, who disappears.  We know in the end that Starbuck was a ghost.  Then was the piano player the cylon Daniel that John had suffocated and killed before he turned on Tigh and the creators?  If not, then did we ever see Daniel in the 2004 series?